# middy/validator: how to write schema for JSON string

Tags: aws-lambda, middleware, jsonschema, serverless-framework

I am trying to validate REST API resp format in Serverless Framework. Using middy/validator

The output schema

```
const outputSchema = {
  required: ['body', 'statusCode'],
  properties: {
    body: {
      type: 'object'
    },
    statusCode: {
      type: 'number'
    }
  }
}
```

in the API

```
const handler = async (event, context) => {
   ...
   return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(resp)
      };
}
...

export const handler = middy(handler).use(
  validator({ outputSchema: outputSchema })
);
```

I received error from validation, I can see that in API, the `body` is a JSON string, but in schema, the `body` is an object.

How can I write a schema to validate the structure of the JSON string

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you stringify the resp object, since this makes things harder. I guess you could apply some regex checks on the stringified JSON: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html

Comment: it's a requirement from Serverless framework

Comment: You'll have to re parse it again to validate it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

The stringified response you are sending will not work with the schema but that response is not specific to serverless - its the response required by the api gateway proxy. Try returning non stringified result and use another middleware to format the response. Check out [autoproxyresponse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/middy-autoproxyresponse). Or write your own to handle the final formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Add "type" property in your defined schema and set it to strict type.
In your case:

```
const schema{
type: 'object' //this!
required: ['body', 'statusCode'],
.....
}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Wow, it worked for me as well! Thanks :)
Why is this not in the examples of
[middy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@middy/validator) ?